# jQuery fadeOut changes/clears window hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, hash, fadeout

While debuging my site, I found out that:

```
/* SOME my-web.com/index/#hash HERE... */
me.slides.eq(me.curID).fadeOut(me.options.fade.interval, me.options.fade.easing, 
    function(){
        /* HERE HASH IS CLEARED: my-web.com/index/# */
    });
```

anyone have any clues why that is? For sure I can store hash in variable before fadeOut and then put it back, but that's kind of 'dirty' hack :)

p/s/ jQuery is 1.5.1.
p/p/s/ i'm talking about window.location.hash, that is: my-web.com/index/#hash

Comment: are you refering to the window url hash?

Comment: @Wes yes, exactly. I edited the original post, so it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The value is likely out of scope from the callback function.  Is the hash set with a var declaration?  Where is it declared?

Comment: i'm talking about window.location.hash, not some variable.